# Could macOS kexts inject code to specific processes (like mach_inject did)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, kernel-extension

While mach_inject was a handy (but risky) solution to inject some of your code to other Apps (mostly used to customize Finder), it doesn't work since 10.11.
Is there a possibility to achieve the same functionality by using some sort of kext?

The purpose of this is to add some visual effects on top of windows for specific apps. Maybe there is a simpler solution, like Accessibility API?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a kext, you can certainly obtain the task handle to any process; this is the part that no longer works from user space since SIP. The `task_t` pointer in the kext can be converted to a special port using `task_get_special_port(task, TASK_KERNEL_PORT, &task_port)`, which you can then send to a user space task using `mach_msg_send_from_kernel()`. Once you have the port in user space you can do the usual things such as allocating, reading & writing memory in the target task, etc. However, if the target task has very strict code signing flags set, any attempt to execute code in memory pages that aren't signed will fail by crashing the process. This means it won't work on most of Apple's own apps. Other methods than code injection may be easier and more secure, as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!